# OnFling and other methods don't work on TextView within ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, gesturedetector

I need help... :-)
I have a custom adapter for my ListView. The items are TextViews.
I want to be able to handle onSingleTap, onFling and all other events on every TextView.
But only onDown event works! All other don't! I don't understand why. In my other activity where TextViews are not a part of a ListView everything works fine...

This is what I have:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
 ...
 private GestureDetector txtProductGD;
 private View.OnTouchListener txtProductGL;
 ...

 public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
  ...
  txtProductGL = new View.OnTouchListener() {
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    txtProductGD = new GestureDetector(new txtProductGestureDetector((TextView) v));

    return txtProductGD.onTouchEvent(event);
   }
  };
  ...
 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 ...
 view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);

 TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtProduct);

 textView.setOnTouchListener(txtProductGL);
 ...
 }

 private class txtProductGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

  private TextView textView;

  public txtProductGestureDetector(TextView textView) {
   this.textView = textView;
  }

  public boolean onDown (MotionEvent e) {
   textView.setText("onDown..."); // IT WORKS!
   return false; 
  }

  public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed (MotionEvent e) {
   textView.setText("onSingleTapConfirmed..."); // IT DOESN'T WORK!
   return false;
  }

  // ALL OTHER METHODS ARE ALSO DON'T WORK!..       
 }                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using your custom class `txtProductGestureDetector` for another reason, but if you are just looking to override the methods for a specific view, try this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtProduct);
textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was DOWN");
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
                return true;     
            default : 
                return true;
            }            
        }
});
```

That can be placed right in your `getView` method, and will assign a touchListener to your textView.